# if inside for each loop pushing multidimensional array - php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm running two for each loops and pushing one of them into the other one. This works fine, except if my I have more than one match. In that case, I'm only getting the last one. Sorry about the title, not too sure how to call this question in one line.

```
foreach($items as &$item) {
    foreach($fruits as &$fruit) {
        $i = 0;
        if($fruit['for']==$item['id']) {
            $item["fruits"][$i] = $fruit;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

First array :

```
array(114) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "76"
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Second array :

```
array(47) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["for"]=>
    string(2) "76"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

With multiple matches of the `if($fruit['for']==$item['id'])` logic, I'd like the following output.

```
array(114) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "76"
    ...
    ["fruits"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["for"]=>
        string(2) "76"
        ...
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "33"
        ["for"]=>
        string(2) "76"
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `$i` to 0 for every array-element you check. This renders the `$i++` useless and your first match gets overwritten. Try either this:

```
foreach($items as &$item) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($fruits as &$fruit) {
        if($fruit['for']==$item['id']) {
            $item["fruits"][$i] = $fruit;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

or this: (depending on what exactly you will need)

```
$i = 0;
foreach($items as &$item) {
    foreach($fruits as &$fruit) {
        if($fruit['for']==$item['id']) {
            $item["fruits"][$i] = $fruit;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, each time you find a new match it gets a new key.

Comment: so that was it.... thank you! I'm not sure how to feel, proud that I'm getting so close (php is new to me), or sad that I didn't see my error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

take `$i` outside the loop, your match is always stored in `$item["fruits"][0]`

```
foreach($items as &$item) {
    $i = 0;   
    foreach($fruits as &$fruit) {
        if($fruit['for']==$item['id']) {
            $item["fruits"][$i] = $fruit;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$i = 0;` inside the first loop is the result I want, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)